# Detecting which languages the app has support for

Tags: android, localization, xamarin.android

Let's suppose I have an app that has support for `English`, `Spanish` and `French` with the following folder structure in the project:

```
root/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

How can I **dynamically** detect that the app has support the support for the additional languages?

---

### EDIT

*Although I think this part is going to be almost impossible, I'll give it a shot...*

On a deeper level, ***IF*** it's possible to achieve what I've mentioned before, is there a way to go *full-dive* on it and detect how far a given language is supported within the app?

Grabbing the example before, let's say that I have this:

```
root/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
               title: Title
               message: Message
               random_message: This is a random message.
       values-es/
           strings.xml
               title: Título
               message: Mensaje
               random_message: Este es un mensaje aleatorio.
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
               title: Titre
               random_message: Ceci est un message aléatoire.
```

*Shout-out to [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com/?hl=pt-PT)!*

How far can I detect that `Spanish` is fully supported by the app, but `French` has 1, or more, missing translations?

---

**Background**

I'm attempting to develop a settings page where the user can set the language of the app. To avoid possible *missing languages* ( e.g.: I have the `strings.xml` for Arabic, but it's not on the list ) or *languages that can be selected but sets all in English instead* ( e.g.: I have Korean on the list, but the `strings.xml` doesn't exist ), I'd like to make this dynamic.

This way, I only would had to add the folders and `strings.xml` and the app would, supposedly, detect the languages for which has support for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that the `values-...` folders that your *app* has gets augmented by the `values-...` folders from the libraries that you use. Your app cannot distinguish between these at runtime.

If you want to treat a *particular set* of resource directories (those in your app) differently, you will need to do so yourself at compile time. For example, you could write a custom Gradle task that iterates over those directories, determines the locales you support, and writes that information somewhere (custom string-array resource, custom Java class, *possibly* `BuildConfig` if you can get the syntax right). Then, at runtime, you would use this generated list as your list of languages that your *app's code* supports.